# Ubuntu unable to boot. I cannot log on. PURPLE SCREEN, please help

Tags: boot, grub2, 18.04

I have a purple screen on my Ubuntu and I am unable to log in. Please help. Thanks........ I have tried numerous times to try fix this problem.

Comment: pleaseeeee don't ask the same question twice. Delete one of the questions please.

Comment: I have tried  and still not working @karel

Answer (score 0):

first time, after installing it? I had the same issue with 18.04 when I installed when I first needed to login it will get stuck on a purple screen... they way I got arround that is re-installed the system and then check the option box "autologin" so it login without needing a password and then I was able to use the system.

The problem at least on my laptop was fixed with the version 18.04.01..

I don't know if that helps you or not XD

Comment: yeahh this is really pissing me off! i got a crazy deadline and i cant log on!. please help. please help, hope you well happy new year. @luis-felipe-carranza

Comment: you just installed the OS?

I'm not sure if it will work, but you can try goin to the recovery terminal (using the grub)

and type:

      sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf

then iyou might be able to enable the autologin.


if not, you can always reinstall, enable autologin and it will took you only 15min, then do a software update and distro uopdate

'sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade'

then disable autologin and might just might work, if not Ubuntu 18.10 never gave a problem like that, maybe you should upgrade :'v

Comment: I have tried but still not working ------------------ = [   I have tried the first but still the same. how do I install enable log in???